# A few beginner questions

Tags: nvidia

Greetings to all here..

I'm a complete Linux virgin, so apologies if anything I'm asking is blatantly obvious.. (I have done a brief search for the issues I'm having)
Please go easy on the terminology.. I've years of Windows to cleanse myself of.

How do I go about deleting files/folders permanently.. I've quite a few GB worth of old Windows files I'd like to remove, but short of moving them to the rubbish bin & then emptying it I can't see any option to permanently delete I've tried rm -r/-f but am told there is no such file or folder.

I have a Nvidia GTX 670 are Linux drivers available & easy enough to install?
I've also been told that the more interesting/useful software is to be found on alternative repo's can someone educate me?

Thanks for listening.

Comment: If you want to delete a file, use the command rm -f FILENAME. To delete a folder, use rm -fr NAMEOFFOLDER.

Comment: This is not WIndows! The drivers that come with Ubuntu are the drivers you WANT to use.

Comment: You've got multiple questions being asked in one question, that's not good form here, typically it's one question, one answer.  Per post.

Comment: To install the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver search in the Dash for *Additional Drivers*, click the Additional Drivers icon to open the Additional Drivers utility, select the latest (Tested) version of the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver, click the *Apply Changes* button to install the graphics driver and reboot to enable the graphics driver.

Comment: Please split this up into multiple questions, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

this for the Nvidia driver

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

& about the the windows file you can use the disk-manage

```
gnome-disks
```

& you can easily remove the windows partition

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply.. once the divers have installed should there be a gui or any other way to control the settings? as I can't see anything. Apologies but I've no idea what you mean by gnome-disks is it a command or should I be downloading something?

Comment: Gnome-disks it's a command to the disks manager